# Volar (vscode extension): line comment syntax in .vue files template section is wrong

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, syntax

I have enabled Volar, the Vscode extension (v0.34.15).
I have disabled the Vetur extension.
Now when commenting out code in the template part of a vue file, the comments have the wrong syntax:

```
{# <p>hello</p> #}
```

instead of

```
<!-- <p>hello</p> -->
```

With Vetur it works like expected, so I don't know if this is caused by some conflict with another extension or if it is some setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: does the syntax highlighting works in the HTML parts of the Vue file, do you see HTML TextMate scopes when inspecting, the Vue TextMate file specifies where HTML parts are, you should create an issue at the Vue language extension

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, solved by disabling some VS Code extensions, **I disabled Vue 3 Snippets and TWIG pack**, now everything works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Twig(Symfony's template engine) extension is enabled and has access to .vue files, please disable it/them.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, it could also be the Antlers Toolbox plugin if you do Statamic work.